# Как при наведении на ссылку выполнить JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть 5 ссылок:

```html
<a class='tv' href='#' data-token='link_1'><img src='graph.png'></a> 
<a class='tv' href='#' data-token='link_2'><img src='graph.png'></a> 
<a class='tv' href='#' data-token='link_3'><img src='graph.png'></a> 
<a class='tv' href='#' data-token='link_4'><img src='graph.png'></a> 
<a class='tv' href='#' data-token='link_5'><img src='graph.png'></a>
```

Мне необходимо, при наведении на них выполнить javascript:

```js
let token = document.querySelector('[data-token]');
token = token.getAttribute('data-token');

new TV.widget({
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": token,
  "interval": "5",
  "timezone": "Europe/Moscow",
  "theme": "dark",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "ru",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "studies": [
    "BB@tv-basicstudies"
  ],
  "show_popup_button": true,
  "popup_width": "1000",
  "popup_height": "650",
  "container_id": token,
});
```

При этом передать параметр data-token в JS скрипт. Понимаю, что делается так:

```js
let token = document.querySelector('[data-token]'); 
token = token.getAttribute('data-token');
```

Подскажите, как правильно это реализовать с помощью jQuery или ещё как, чтобы при наведении на ссылку, передался параметр (data - атрибут) и соответственно выполнился скрипт ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

как-то так. Инициализируете при первом наведении, с помощью `one`. Объект, если надо записываете в data-атрибут, если может понадобится позже.

```js
$(".tv").one('mouseover', function(){
  let token = $(this).data('token');
  
  let tv = new TV.widget({ tokenValue: token });  
  
  $(this).data('tv', tv);   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='tv' href='#' data-token='link_1'><img src='graph.png'></a> 
<a class='tv' href='#' data-token='link_2'><img src='graph.png'></a> 
<a class='tv' href='#' data-token='link_3'><img src='graph.png'></a> 
<a class='tv' href='#' data-token='link_4'><img src='graph.png'></a> 
<a class='tv' href='#' data-token='link_5'><img src='graph.png'></a>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! У меня в итоге полностью исчезает страница и остается только виджет на белом фоне, а мне необходимо чтобы при наведении показывался виджет, а когда курсор уходит из зоны виджета, он закрывался

Comment: Вы задали вопрос: "Как при наведении на ссылку выполнить JS?" вариант выше - ответ на ваш вопрос.
Я бы еще и для `mouseout` событие описал

Comment: @ConstantineTretyakoff для `mouseout` это уже то чего автор просит в комментариях, к начальному вопросу не относится.